# Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable

Tags: react-native

I'm a react native beginner.
If it's just a silly question,, oops, I'll appreciate bearing with me.

I've got this error.
It's an output of `npm run ios` after I edited something (sorry I don't know what it's the trigger.)

```
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

Here is the app.js.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Login from './components/FirstPages/LoginPage';
import Signup from './components/FirstPages/SignupPage';
import First from './components/FirstPages/FirstPage';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}>
              <Stack.Screen name="First Screen" component={First} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Signup Screen" component={Signup} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Login Screen" component={Login} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.10",
    "@rneui/base": "4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "4.0.0-rc.7",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "4.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-check": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.18.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "0.6.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Sae } from 'react-native-textinput-effects';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      email: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.total}>
        <View style={styles.AppName}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>
            Hi!
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.Inputs}>
          <Sae
          label="Email"
          iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
          iconName="pencil"
          iconColor="white"
          inputPadding={16}
          labelHeight={24}
          borderHeight={2}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          />
          <Sae
          label="Password"
          iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
          iconName="pencil"
          iconColor="white"
          inputPadding={16}
          labelHeight={24}
          borderHeight={2}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  total: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  AppName: {
    flex: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Inputs: {
    flex: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default Login;
```

SignupPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Sae } from 'react-native-textinput-effects';

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      email: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.total}>
        <View style={styles.AppName}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>
            Hi!
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.Inputs}>
          <Sae
          label="Email"
          iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
          iconName="pencil"
          iconColor="white"
          inputPadding={16}
          labelHeight={24}
          borderHeight={2}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          />
          <Sae
          label="Password"
          iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
          iconName="pencil"
          iconColor="white"
          inputPadding={16}
          labelHeight={24}
          borderHeight={2}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  total: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  AppName: {
    flex: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Inputs: {
    flex: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default Signup;
```

FirstPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-textinput-effects';

function FirstPage({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.total}>
      <View style={styles.AppName}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>
            SMS
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.Buttons}>
        <Button
          type="OutLine"
          title="Login"
          containerStyle={{ width: 110, height: 45, margin: 10 }}
          titleStyle={{ fontSize: 25 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login Screen')}
          />
        <Button
          type="OutLine"
          title="Sign up"
          containerStyle={{ width: 110, height: 45, margin: 10 }}
          titleStyle={{ fontSize: 25 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signup Screen')}
          />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  total: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  AppName: {
    flex: 4,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  Buttons: {
    flex: 4.5,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default FirstPage;
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34688

I found it, but it seemed there's no solution.